# Executing a command on the command line and reading the console output in Java

Tags: java, command-line, process

I need to get the hostId of my server using a Java program. Is there something in the Java API that is built-in which can help me do this?

```
lab.com$ hostid
f9y7777j -> How can I get this using java
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java runtime.getruntime() getting output from executing a command line program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would allow you to run a console command and store the result:-

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("hostid");
 Process p = pb.start();
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
 String line = null;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
 {
    // Store returned string here.
 }
 reader.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

`System.out.println(java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());`