# Passing parameters from a Java program to shell script

Tags: java, jsp, shell, servlets

I am developing a web application wherein I am using JSP as my front end and shell script as my back end. Thus I would be passing parameters from input JSP to the shell script via a Java Program(Business Layer). I would like to know how would I be able to pass parameters from Java to shell script and execute the same.Thank you.

Comment: Similar to this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program

Comment: Use ProcessBuilder with the [command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#command(java.util.List)) method to pass arguments.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ProcessBuilder` to pass parameter to shell script.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("shellscript", "myArg1", "myArg2");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
env.remove("OTHERVAR");
env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
pb.directory("myDir");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I have a question, Are "myArg1" and "myArg2" the arguments passed to the shell scripts. If that is the case, I am not getting the use of VAR1 and VAR2. Also if I need to do some processing in the shell script with the help of "myArg1" and "myArg2" and get some results, how would I transfer that result back to my Java program. I have analyzed about this in many forums but I am not able to find an answer. Could you please help me.

Comment: I have figured out the answer and I think this might be helpful for people

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the answer and I think this might be helpful for people. 
Please refer to the code

```
public static BufferedReader process() throws IOException  
{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/XXXX/Desktop/request.sh","Apple");
    String line; 
    Process process=pb.start(); 
    java.io.InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    return br;

}
```

Here "Apple" is the input parameter for the shell script and that will be stored in $1(environmental variable) and this could be accessed from shell script and when something needs to be sent from shell script to Java, echo from shell script and get that from `process.inputStream()` in Java ..