# Open file with default program using java 1.4

Tags: java, desktop-application, desktop

The Desktop.getDestop().open(File) launches the associated aplication to open the file.

The Desktop class is available since Java 1.6 - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html

How to do the same using the 1.4 Java version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following to open files with the default application:

```
    /* build up command and launch */
    String command = "";
    String file = "FILE IN HERE";
    if (isLinux()) {
        command = "xdg-open " + file;
    } else if (isWindows()) {
        command = "cmd /C start " + file;
    } else
        return;

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

available since 1.0: [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).

Comment: You can use [Apache commons-exec's `OS` class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/OS.html) to determine the host operating system at runtime.

Comment: On Windows, if I start an executable using `cmd /C start` as you suggested, I don't get any information on whether it successfully started. Do you know of any workaround for this?

Comment: @Zoltán You can read the output using one of the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program).

Comment: @Zoltán Or use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616733/runtime-exec-lp-command-print-success).

Comment: What I meant is - if I use `cmd /C start` command, I lose the handle to the process because it starts a command window which in turn start my target process and exits.

Comment: At my machine the `xdg-open` command is not exectued when I call it like this from my `java`, but when I try to execute the exact same command in a terminal window, it works. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.exec()`

More details can be found at:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html