# Runtime exec lp command print success

Tags: java, printing

I have to print a PDF file in java program and make sure it's printed successfully, else throw exception.

My Code is:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lp -c -n 1 -d 1.2.3.4 abc.pdf");
System.out.println(p.waitFor());
```

Above code prints 0, but it only confirms that job is submitted fine, how to make sure that it's printed also.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Run lpstat (after lp) and capture the process output.