# Get process output without blocking

Tags: java, git, stdout

I want to get a process' output (`Git.exe` to be exact) and convert it to a String object. Previously sometimes my code was blocked. Then I figured out that it's because the process' `ErrorStream` has some output and I have to manually capture that (which I'm not interested in). I changed my code to this:

```
public static String runProcess(String executable, String parameter) {
    try {
        String path = String.format("%s %s", executable, parameter);
        Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);

        // ignore errors
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(pr.getErrorStream(), errors);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(pr.getInputStream(), writer);

        pr.waitFor();
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now it works mostly fine, but then again, sometimes it gets blocked again in this line:
`IOUtils.copy(pr.getErrorStream(), errors);`.

Is there some way I could just get the output from the `git.exe` without hitting a block? Thanks.

Comment: You should use a `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: @fge Will it make a difference? Could you please explain more? Thanks.

Comment: It will: you can redirect stdout/stderr like you want and run the process without waiting for stdout/stderr to be swallowed.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, but if you're trying to create a java wrapper for git, I suggest you to take a look a [jgit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this [beautiful article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) and the `StreamGobbler` class described there (which I modified a little) I solved the problem. My implementation of `StreamGobbler`:

```
class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
    InputStream is;
    String output;

    StreamGobbler(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(is, writer);
            output = writer.toString();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and my function is:

```
public static String runProcess(String executable, String parameter) {
    try {
        String path = String.format("%s %s", executable, parameter);
        Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);

        StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(pr.getErrorStream());
        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(pr.getInputStream());

        // kick them off concurrently
        errorGobbler.start();
        outputGobbler.start();

        pr.waitFor();
        return outputGobbler.getOutput();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: outputGobbler.getOutput() will return null in cases where the streamgobbler threads haven't had a chance to read in the input before the process is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Use ProcessBuilder or Apache commons-exec.

Your posted code has bugs, this is a hard topic to get right.

Comment: Could you please post a demo code? Also, please tell me what bugs are in my code. Thanks.