# Linux find command from java not working

Tags: java, linux, process

Can anyone help me get this code working in linux

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception,{   
    String s ="find . -exec ls -al {} \\;";
    Process exec = Runtime
            .getRuntime()
            .exec(s);
    exec.waitFor();
System.out.println(s);
    if (exec.getErrorStream().available() != 0) {
        BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(
                exec.getErrorStream());
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(bf);
        System.out.println(din.readLine());
    }

    System.out.println(exec.exitValue());
}
```

I am getting the following output.

```
find . -exec ls -al {} \;
find: missing argument to `-exec'
1
```

Comment: You are printing from the error stream. You probably want the process's standard output.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441652/get-process-output-without-blocking

Comment: Currently I have an exit code of 1. I want exit code of 0(Success) . I am printing the error stream because I have exit code of 1(fail). Any of you guys got this code work with exit code of 0, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
String[] params = {"find", ".", "-exec", "ls", "-al", "{}", ";"};
```

instead of your plain String command.

Be careful though: The output is heavy (I tested with /dev/.) and the waitFor method may cause your I/O Buffer to burst.

Comment: To elaborate on this answer:  Calling `exec(String)` is unwise.  It is far more reliable to call `exec(String[])`, which needs no backslash-escapes or quoting of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Too many backslash

```sh
find . -exec ls -al {} ';'
```