# How to open Terminal and execute command using java code in OSX

Tags: java, terminal, osx-mavericks

How to launch terminal and execute some commands using java code in MAC?

Similar question i have found for LINUX OS from below link.

[how to run a command at terminal from java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356405/how-to-run-a-command-at-terminal-from-java-program)

Comment: execute java commands or os commands?

Comment: os commands like rm filename

Comment: It is absolutely the same as for Linux, you should look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15356548/1828937

Comment: Do you really need to open a terminal window or do you need to display the output and accept input from the console?

Answer (score 0):

Use Apple Script Editor to open Terminal and run your code.

For Example :

```
String action1 = jsonDriver.readApplicationDetails("OFF");
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String applescriptCommand = "tell application \"Terminal\"\n" + 
         "activate\n" + "delay 1\n" + "tell application \"System Events\"\n" + 
         "keystroke \"" + action1 + "\"\n" + "end tell\n" + "end tell"; 
String[] args1 = { "osascript", "-e", applescriptCommand };
Process process = runtime.exec(args1);
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to run it using bash executable like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c **YouTerminalSoftWareName**");
```

YouTerminalSoftWareName must be absolute path or aready in your PATH environment variable

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c  /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app"); I am doing like this but not able to open terminal

Comment: Yes: this will execute the command, but it will not open a terminal window