# Opening terminal in mac through java

Tags: java, macos, process, console, exec

I am using following code to open cmd in windows and execute the cd command and its working fine for me.
`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \" cd C:\\Users"");`

I want to do the same in mac by opening console, so what should i write instead of cmd ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650193/how-to-open-terminal-and-execute-command-using-java-code-in-osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run it using `bash` executable like this:

```
String[] args = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c", "your_command", "with", "args"};
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
```

**Follow this link:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15356451/1715121

Comment: I want to run a python script from the same and pass parameter to it through args, so how can i do that ????

Comment: String para="here is parameter to python script";                              
cmd="cd /users/downloads/ && python myScript.py" ;                           
String []args ={ "bin/bash" , "-c" , cmd , para };                                             its not working.