# Java ProcessBuilder get Output from Linux Terminal Commands

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder

I want to communicate with the linux terminal with java code. I want to store the output and work with it. I implemented the code below following the instructions in given link.

I would expect the complete terminal output of help. But neither for the standard commands, nor for the mosquitto commands I get anything from the input stream. Where is the mistake? Or are you supposed to do it completely differnt?

Stackoverflow link: [how to run a command at terminal from java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356405/how-to-run-a-command-at-terminal-from-java-program#15356451)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class LinuxInputStream
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Linux Terminal
        String prefix = "/bin/bash";
        String terminalCommand = "help";
        String mosquittoCommand = "mosquitto --help";

        ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder(
                new String[] {prefix, terminalCommand});
        ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder(
                new String[] {prefix, mosquittoCommand});

        try
        {
            executeCommand(pb1);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IO Error in Terminal Command execution!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            executeCommand(pb2);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IO Error in Mosquitto Command execution!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void executeCommand(ProcessBuilder pb) throws IOException
    {
        Process terminalCommandProcess = pb.start();
        InputStream inputStream = terminalCommandProcess.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Line: " + line);
            i++;
        }
        if (i == 0) System.out.println("Nothing read from input stream");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Nothing read from input stream 
> Nothing read from input stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution immidiatly after the post: The "-c" part is missing. Correct code snippet is:

```
        // Linux Terminal
        String prefix = "/bin/bash";
        String c = "-c";
        String terminalCommand = "help";
        String mosquittoCommand = "mosquitto --help";

        ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder(
                new String[] {prefix, c, terminalCommand});
        ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder(
                new String[] {prefix, c, mosquittoCommand});
```

Comment: Using `ProcessBuilder#redirectErrorStream(true)` at-least during testing merges stdout and stderr and helps find these kind of errors faster.