# Run a program and have it output to JPanel/JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I would like to know if it is possible to run a program (ie Google Chrome, Skype etc) and have it output onto my JPanel/JFrame (so I can have Google Chrome inside my Application). And if so, how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program

Comment: You mean text output or graphical "output"?

Comment: "I can have a google chrome inside my application" would be best expressed as "put a google chrome **component** inside my application". So, go to google "chrome component for java". Alternative wording may refer to SDK (Software Development Kit), API or libraries. Note: I do not think it exists, but there are some browsers made in java that may be available as components.

Comment: Ouch, you can't just put any program in a swing ui...

Comment: [This one](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) is opensource, you probably could embed it in your program!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it´s possible if the applications have an java api (an interface for you the developer) google chrome you could open without an api just as a normal browser and go to a targeted website for example :) 
just do a google search i found on the first google site some java apis for skype for example
this one  https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api

and use them

i hope i could help you :)