# Java program that executes only when (non-user) input is received via a file

Tags: java, c, multithreading, pipe, simulated-annealing

as part of my research project, I have written a Java search program that implements simulated annealing. However, this search doesn't only occur in the Java program as I am supposed to compute the overall cost function using another program written in C. So basically the search routine would be like this:

Example cost function: minimize {A + B}
where the first part of the expression, A, would be done in my program and the second part, B, would be the regularization term computed from a C program. I know it seems really strange that I have to do this but I don't have the time/resources/proper background to re-implement that regularization program as part of my Java program. Basically I am trying to search for the optimum vector of values through a two-part search.

I wish to output the current solution (as a formatted file which the C program understands) from Java and feed it to the C program to do its regularization (I have done this part). This is where I'm stuck at: While the C program is running, I wish to make my Java program wait until it receives input (in the form of a file) back from the C program. So basically my program gives input to the other program and then stops its execution (for the time being) until that C program has done its job and returned a file of values for re computation of values to be used in the next iteration of the annealing search.

I'm guessing I should use some sort of thread methods like wait and notify but I'm really not sure. It would be pretty straightforward if the program depended on user input. But the program, as it stands, executes only upon receiving the file input.

Please advise! And I apologise in advance if this question is verbose and confusing. I am wiling to clarify any questions. Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java runtime.getruntime() getting output from executing a command line program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program)

Answer (score 0):

Basically this:

[java runtime.getruntime() getting output from executing a command line program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program)

When you're ready for the C part, you spawn the Process via Runtime.exec(), open the input and output stream, feed in your data in the format it recognizes, and then read back the eventual result from it's output stream and parse it.