# No output when running system commands from a Java program

Tags: java, stdio

This is the code that attempts to run the system command:

```
String command = "java -cp 1outinstr;out Main";
Process p      = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + command);
```

My problem is that **I can't see the command's output.**

Answer (score 5):

The command is running fine, it's just not connected to the console.

If you want to see the commands's output, you'll have to print it yourself:

```
String command = "java -cp 1outinstr;out Main";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + command);

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        p.getInputStream()));

BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        p.getErrorStream()));

// read the output from the command
System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
String s = null;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

// read any errors from the attempted command
System.out
        .println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

[code taken from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5711150/924313)

If you want to learn more, read about [standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams):

> In computer programming, standard streams are preconnected input and
>   output channels between a computer program and its environment
>   (typically a text terminal) when it begins execution. The three I/O
>   connections are called standard input (stdin), standard output
>   (stdout) and standard error (stderr). *- from Wikipedia*

Comment: Perhaps offer an explanation of *how* to connect it to the console, or see the output in another way.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 String command="java -cp 1outinstr;out Main"
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( // "cmd - for windows only"
                        "cmd /c " + command);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))
    while(in.readline != null)
    {
    String output = in.readline();
    System.out.println(output);
    }
```