# how can i recover the result of Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dir"); in JTextArea in java

Tags: java

How can I recover the result of

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dir");
```

in JTextArea in java programming language.Best regards;

Comment: Please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5711150/1089811).

Comment: use the `java streams` to combine the `inputstream` from one to the `outputstream` of other.

Comment: i used these instructions in my code that it returns to me an exception : public static String execCmd(String cmd) throws java.io.IOException {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }