# how can I use command line in java programs?

Tags: java, maven, command

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec("mvn -version");
            InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
            InputStreamReader isrerr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
            BufferedReader brerr = new BufferedReader(isrerr);
            InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isrin = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
            BufferedReader brin = new BufferedReader(isrin);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = brerr.readLine()) != null)
               System.out.println(line);
            while ((line = brin.readLine()) != null)
               System.out.println(line);
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
       } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

this code doesn't work well,there isn't output,and the process can't stop.

help me!thank advance.I want to execute maven command in java program by invoking command line,but it output error:it will output error java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn":
but if i run the same command int the command line , it works well.

Comment: This is a duplicate post see this for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program

Comment: i tried but it still output error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the process output with `proc.getInputStream()`

Unless you know your program is always returning trivial amounts of output, it's best to read both the error stream and the input stream in separate threads.

Then use `proc.waitFor()` and get your output from the reader threads.

Otherwise, your process may block, because it cannot deliver it's output.

Sample code:
    import java.io.*;

```
public class Test {

    static class StreamReader extends Thread {
        InputStream stream;
        StreamReader(InputStream stream) {
            this.stream = stream;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stream);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = null;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(line);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec("mvn -version");
            new StreamReader(proc.getInputStream()).start();
            new StreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()).start();
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it will output error  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program    "mvn": CreateProcess error=2,
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:470)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
 at com.uestc.maven.MavenCMD.main(MavenCMD.java:11)
    but my run "mvn -version" in the command line it's OK.

Comment: Can you provide the exact code that generates that message?

Comment: I updated my answer with sample code that runs on my system

Comment: I tried your example but it still output  the same error:Cannot run program "mvn": CreateProcess error=2

Comment: Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 21:51:
28+0800)
Maven home: D:\JAVASoftWare\apache-maven-3.0.5  thanks ,and this is the correct output when i run "mvn -version" in the command line.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the Maven directory in your default PATH.
You must either give the full path of mvn (probably D:\JAVASoftWare\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\mvn) or add the directory to your PATH environment.

Comment: I set the PATH environment D:\JAVASoftWare\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;so i  can get  correct output when i solely run "mvn -version" in the outside command line.

Comment: Are you running java from some IDE which was started before you set the PATH variable?

Comment: first thanks ,and I use eclipse,but i restart it many times.it output the same error.

Comment: I use a .bat file to replace the command ,and it can work now.thanks.