# process continues to run after using Java exec

Tags: java, android, adb

I have the following method

```
public static void disableMobileDate()
{
    try
    {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = null;
        pr = rt.exec("C:\\Program Files\\Android\\android-sdk\\platform-tools\\adb shell svc data disable");
        System.out.println("### Data disabled on mobile device! ###");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Every time this method is ran from my program, it creates a adb.exe in task manager. The adb.exes (multiple adb.exe processes) stays there until I close my program. Is there anyway to make the process end after the command has been successfully executed?

Comment: it's by design - leave it be

Comment: @AlexP.--terrible answer. I just had to kill over 300 instances of `adb.exe`. Is that also by design? Should I have left them be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `pr.destroy()` after your command execution.

Or you can kill the process via the `taskkill` command:

```
rt.exec("taskkill /F /IM adb.exe")
```

Comment: The `taskkill` isn't cross platform compatible.

Comment: True, but `rt.exec("C:\\Program Files\\Android\\android-sdk\\platform-tools\\adb shell svc data disable");` isn't either.

Comment: `taskkill` is a DOS command that can be run from DOS Command prompt like so to kill all instances of the executable adb.exe like so: `taskkill /F /IM adb.exe`, where `/F` means to kill forcefully and `/IM ...` specifies the image name. Surely there's a similar command with similar syntax in Linux or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the process by doing `pr.destroy()` to kill. But you should listen for the update that comes out, and once it prints what you are looking for, then you should kill it. A way to get the output is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program).