# How to I exit a while loop after starting a process in Java?

Tags: java, process, android-emulator, kill-process

Just found this post (and found the code which I'm also pasting below):

[java runtime.getruntime() getting output from executing a command line program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program/30319110#30319110)

My question is, how do I kill the process? It seems that the code blocks in the while loop. I've tried several options like using a boolean, running all the code in a separate thread and stuff like this, but without any success.
I just want to start an Android emulator and kill it whenever I want.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] commands = {"emulator", "-avd", "jenkins", 
                    "-scale", "96dpi", "-dpi-device", "100"};
Process proc = rt.exec(commands);

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

// read the output from the command
System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
String s = null;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

// read any errors from the attempted command
System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: You want to kill the thread which actually get `ErrorStream from Console` with another Thread ?

Comment: I just want to stop the emulator when I don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.

Use below code to get The Process ID of that current running thread or Process.

```
  String processName =java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
  String ProcessID = processName.split("@")[0];//Process Id
```

Use that Process ID to kill that Process in your CPU.

I think for that purpose you may wish to write any other trigger or any condition in While loop.