# elastic search query using curl in java

Tags: java, curl, elasticsearch

I have the following query which i am able to run through command line :

```
 curl -XPOST "http://35.160.73.241:9201/products/_search" -d 
                                  "{"query":{"match":{"campaign_id":"12239"}}}"
```

I need to run the above query using java. I am using the following code :

```
     try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl -XPOST
                        \"http://35.160.73.241:9201/products/_search\" -d
                       \"{\"query\":{\"match\":{\"campaign_id\":\"12239\"}}}\"");
            int resultCode = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println(resultCode);
            if (resultCode == 0) {
                // all is good
            } 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // process cause
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it is giving me the following exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": CreateProcess 
                     error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Please help me to run the query using Java.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just use a [java client](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-java-clients-for-elasticsearch) for elastic search instead of using curl. There are distinct advantages, such as being able to construct queries easily and being aware of cluster state

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment. Try this:

```
String env = new String[] { "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin/" };
String[] cmd = new String[] {"curl", "-XPOST", "\"http://35.160.73.241:9201/products/_search\"", "-d", "\"{\"query\":{\"match\":{\"campaign_id\":\"12239\"}}}\""}
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env);
```

This will work if you're using a `Linux` system.

A better solution will be to use [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). Which is the usual way of creating HTTP connections and it's system independent.

Comment: i am using windows

Comment: @ShivyeshAgnihotri In that case. Replace the `env` array with: `{ "curl=/path/to/curl.exe" }` or something like that.

Comment: @ShivyeshAgnihotri  You can also try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"A://path/to/curl.exe", "-XPOST", "\"http://35.160.73.241:9201/products/_search\"", "-d", "\"{\"query\":{\"match\":{\"campaign_id\":\"12239\"}}}\""})`

Comment: i am not getting the exception now but how will i get the result of the query ?

Comment: @ShivyeshAgnihotri You can use `process.getInputStream()` to get the process' input stream and read from it. You can find more details [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5711150/1552587)

Comment: it is giving me something like this - java.io.BufferedInputStream@4517d9a3

Comment: @ShivyeshAgnihotri You need to read from the `BufferedInputStream` not print/write to file the object. Take a better look at the example I've provided in my previous commend especially the `while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)....` part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QueryBuilders for query the elasticsearch.
org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders

Here are some examples:
[Java Code Examples for org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders)