# How to get results from SQLite3 query in Android using root

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to access a database using root and sqlite3 to get data from it.

So far I managed to display data in the logcat but I can't get it in a file or any other way.

Using [RootCommand library](https://github.com/Free-Software-for-Android/RootCommands)  this is my code :

```
public void readDB(String message){
    try {
        Shell shell = Shell.startRootShell();
        String setOutput= "sqlite3 .output /sdcard/number.txt"; // This didn't work because it treats .output as a database name
        String readTest = "sqlite3  /data/data/com.package/databases/someDB.db \"SELECT * FROM table\";";

        shell.add(new SimpleCommand(setOutput)).waitForFinish();
        shell.add(new SimpleCommand(readTest)).waitForFinish();
        Log.d(TAG , "finished");
    } catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

As explained [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html)  I used `.output` to specify a file but it didn't work because it treats `.output` as a database name and throws an exception that it can't find the db and continues to display results in logcat.

And I tried `writefile('/sdcard/myfile.txt',column)` but no file and no data in logcat.

When I try `.output /sdcard/myfile.txt` from adb it works fine and I find the results in the file but I can't get it done through the code

So how to get this data in anyway? Is there any better approach to do this?

PS: I'm not accessing my own app data so I can't use sqlite database helper class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this:

1. Do really mean file of database is `/data/data/com.package/databases/someDB.db` ??? all android devices store their databases is `/data/data/com.package/databases/someDB`
2. Have you tried full copy file from app `/data/data/com.package/databases/someDB` into `/sdcard/myolddb_in_newplace` ?
3. Have you tried to use pipes ?  like here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111610/125332

Comment: 1. Yes this is file of database
2. Copying database is not an option because it's very big and changes very fast and I'll query it every time it changes.
3. Solved the problem. Thank you

Comment: Is there anyway to get the result as a String variable?

Comment: What do you mean? read the url I wrote. You can output the command line log both String and file

Comment: I mean like `String result = theQueryResult` instead of writing it into a file and the link doesn't show this approach. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. You can use `Process` class to read stdout: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5711150/1979882