# How to run commands on Ubuntu terminal by using a java application.?

Tags: java, terminal, command, ubuntu-16.04

I want to use a tool which is command based(from ubuntu terminal). I want to run commands from inside a java application. I m currently using eclipse for my work.

So far I have tried to use Runtime.exec("xterm") to open the terminal, but I don't know how to run commands on that terminal using java. Also I don't want the terminal to show up on screen, it should run in the background.

Comment: Do you need to ssh into a different machine or run commands locally?

Comment: Is the command interactive?  Does it require input from the user?  Can that input be fed via the command’s standard input?

Comment: My problem was solved by using this method:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program