# Redirect console output to a custom LogBack appender

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, appender, console-output

Today I have started using LogBack in combination with SLF4J for my project. I have been trying to redirect all console output (From my own project and others) to a custom appender.

The final goal is to redirect all the output to a [Discord](https://discordapp.com/) chat channel.

I have looked into the following approach:
[java runtime.getruntime() getting output from executing a command line program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program) but it wasn't successful.

I am aiming for the following structure:

1. Console message is sent by another library
2. Catch the message and process it

I have tried the following implementation:

```
public class DiscordAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {
    @Override
    protected void append(ILoggingEvent eventObject) {
        SomeDiscordClient.sendMessage(specificChannel, eventObject.getFormattedMessage());
    }
}
```

With the following logback.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="DISCORD" class="package.DiscordAppender"/>

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="DISCORD"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

But this approach is not working, hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: Simpler suggestion - avoid outputting to the console, output to the logger only.

Comment: @BoristheSpider how would i do that when i don't have control over the other output sources (In this case [Bukkit](https://bukkit.org/))

Comment: [`System.setOut`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream))? Or, even better, use [their recommendations](http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/sysout-over-slf4j/faq.html).

Comment: I have tried the implementation, it works but it doesn't catch everything that gets send, [this](https://github.com/Scarsz/DiscordSRV/blob/master/src/main/java/github/scarsz/discordsrv/objects/log4j/ConsoleAppender.java) is what i am trying to achieve but using LogBack