# How to get git -log of all branches in Java?

Tags: java, git

I have a task to implement a program in Java (pure Java without 3rd party libraries) that reads a history of any git repository and puts the commits into tree data structure.
[image]

Could you give me any hints? How to read git log in Java without 3rd party libraries?

Comment: If you are not allowed to use 3rd party libs like jgit, you will need to study [git internals](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals), and, basically, reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Will it take much much time?

Comment: Yes, parsing command output yourself generally takes more time

Comment: Can u give me any hints that can help me to parse it? I think I can put branches in LinkedHashSet but how can I establish connections(merges etc) between them?

Comment: Give an example of output you're trying to parse and the code you've tried in the question, please

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at **[Processes and Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html)** and how to execute a command in the runtime. It does have some details and need fundamental understanding of `java.lang.Runtime`, `java.io` and some other relevant topics, so that I'd refrain to write a whole method here and recommend you to search for a good tutorial and also get the first idea from other questions here, like → [getting output from executing a command line program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program#5711150)