# How can I read from terminal (Ubuntu) output in Java code (output never ends / quit)

Tags: java, android, sockets, terminal

Ubuntu 19.10
Using inellij latest version
Java

Purpose:
With java code use the terminal to monitor and verify tests on android device,
For example tcpdump command on android device
Logcat command and so on,

The problem is that if the output always listen / write the java can't get the strings,
Only if I am shutting the terminal (ctrl c) and then the java gets the strings at once,

What I need is to get the real time output that the terminal provide, seems that the terminal is locked and I understand that I need to open a socket connection to read the output in real time ?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If a program buffers its output, there is nothing you can do to flush that text, unless the program has command-line options to enable auto-flush. Many programs will auto-flush when stdout is a console, but will buffer if stdout is file or a pipe, for performance reasons.

Comment: This is a buffer reader, no files in this case

Comment: You cannot read content of a terminal window, but you can read the output of a console program. This is described in the article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program

Comment: @Eyal What is a buffered reader? I'm talking about the stdout as `tcpdump` sees it. Since `tcpdump` is not a Java program, there is no buffered reader. `tcpdump` will see that its stdout is a pipe. (The pipe is to your Java program, but `tcpdump` doesn't know that.)

Comment: tcpdump is just example for a command that are continue to monitor, never quit, logcat is also a good example that I can't get the strings in real time from the buffer reader

Answer (score 0):

For `tcpdump`, use the `--immediate-mode` command-line option.

> **--immediate-mode**
>
> Capture in "immediate mode". In this mode, packets are delivered to tcpdump as soon as they arrive, rather than being buffered for efficiency. This is the default when printing packets rather than saving packets to a ``savefile'' if the packets are being printed to a terminal rather than to a file or pipe.

Comment: I guess I was missunderstood, My java code sometimes ude tcpdump, sometimes logcat on order to catch issues in real time, I am using the java to open the termial:  ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
                    processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "adb -s 192.168.1.199 shell tcpdump -vv -i eth0 -s 0 | grep error");
                    Process proc = null;
                    proc = processBuilder.start();

Comment: The problem that in this way I can't get strings, that's really bad for me

Comment: @Eyal See [comment by Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60135084/how-can-i-read-from-terminal-ubuntu-output-in-java-code-output-never-ends-q/60135295?noredirect=1#comment106358704_60135084).

Comment: @Eyal You said *"Only if I am shutting the terminal (ctrl c) and then the java gets the strings at once"*. How is Java getting the strings from the terminal, if it is not getting piped the output, as shown in the link provided by Stefan?