# How to execute linux service from java code

Tags: java, linux

I have a service in linux called appSevice, when I start/stop with these cmd, it works :

```
sudo systemctl start appSevice.service;
sudo systemctl stop  appSevice.service;
```

but the problem when I tried to execute these from JAVA code, I tried form exemple :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo systemctl stop appService.service");
```

but it didnt work, I can that the service is always running, any suggestions please to resolve this problem ?

```
service :

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/soft/v1/launchAppService.ksh start
User=Jms-User
Restart=on-abort
```

Comment: you execute it with `sudo`. who is providing the password? it is it `nopasswd`?

Comment: remove `sudo` from your command, what it'll be happen if it's asking you for root password ? instead, run your java program with user having appropriate rights. execute the command line with the correct function: `Process exec(String[] cmdarray)
This method executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process.`

Comment: yes I think this is the problem (password is problem), is there a way to execute these command without providing password ?

Comment: @ Halayem Anis , can you give an exemple of your commande please ?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to help you execute a system command via java program:

1. create user and give him rights to execute `systemctl` command, see
   this thread [allowing user to run systemctl/systemd services without
   password](https://askubuntu.com/a/692712)
2. execute your java program using this user
3. your java code should be:
   `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"systemctl", "stop", "appService.service"});`

the first argument is the command to
execute, others are the arguments

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I use alreadya  user. to execute the jar ..I tries your commande it doesnt work..when I executed sudo systemctl status appService.service; I can see that the service is running

Comment: @Javauser never, never.... never execute a program with root privileges !

Comment: I know..because usually I run and stop the services using linuw commande line with :sudo systemctl start appService.service;sudo systemctl stop appService.service; but now I want to do that with java programatically

Comment: what did you get from standard or error output ? this thread will help you to get the output of a command execution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program

Comment: I got this error :Failed to stop appService.service: Interactive authentication required.See system logs and 'systemctl status appService.service' for details

Comment: look at the edit please ..i have already a user called Jms-User

Answer (score 0):

There is one way also. Create new user with LimitedRoot capabilities and use VISUDO to allow the user to run systemctl/systemd services without entering a password.

Example:

```
%LimitedRootUser ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart appService.service
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but where I have to add this line ?

Comment: Your welcome. login into your Linux machine and type sudo su and then enter your admin password and then type visudo command