# Executing User Input Commands from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I want to execute a set of Maven commands in Command Prompt (Windows or Linux), one after another. Some of the commands will take an input from  user.

I want this to be run using Spring boot. I am using following

```
    Process process = builder.start();
    MyExecutor executor = 
      new MyExecutor(process.getInputStream(), System.out::println);
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(streamGobbler);      
    exitCode = process.waitFor();`
```

This code runs well and able to execute commands in bash/cmd. But it does not prompt the input screen. However the bash/cmd script prompts.

Any suggestion would be helpful here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can solve this problem like this as it mentioned in here; [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program)

Comment: Thanks for quick response but none of these are working when integrating with Spring Boot CommandLineRunner. The program gets stuck or does not prompt for any input.