# php/java bridge call php application through java application

Tags: php-java-bridge

I am new in PHP/Java bridge I installed it successfully and am also successful to call a Java function through PHP script, but I just want to do the exact opposite of this is that I want to call a PHP script in Java application via this bridge and I am not able to find any documentation regarding this. 
can please anyone help me out with this.
please reply!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please refer this post already in Stack overflow

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861006/best-way-to-call-a-local-php-script-from-a-local-java
```

Comment: I saw that example, but its embedding PHP script inside the Java code I just want to call a method of that script from Java.